# Boot up problem

Tags: boot

I have just installed the latest version of Ubuntu onto my laptop and it required a restart in order to finalise the installation. However once my laptop started to boot back up a pop up appears with the message:

```
Boot failure: a proper digital signature was not found. 
One of the files on the selected boot device was rejected by the Secure Boot feature.
```

Any ideas around this?

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Switch off secure boot and boot.

Comment: George, how do I switch off secure boot? I can't get into anything to switch anything off?

Comment: Its in the BIOS options.

Comment: Great, glad it worked out.

Answer (score 1):

The OP clarified in a comment that they disabled secure boot to solve the problem:

> [I did it, thank you – Con-r Jan 5 '17 at 19:02](https://askubuntu.com/questions/868414/boot-up-problem#comment1344798_868414)